# Edit the values of an XML file using math

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML document with contents like so:

```
<CHandlingDataMgr>
    <HandlingData>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>AIRTUG</handlingName>
            <fMass value="1400.000000" />
            <fSteeringLock value="30.000000" />
            <SubHandlingData>
                <Item type="NULL" />
                <Item type="NULL" />
                <Item type="NULL" />
            </SubHandlingData>
        </Item>
        <Item type="CHandlingData">
            <handlingName>ADDER</handlingName>
            <fMass value="1800.000000" />
            <fSteeringLock value="42.000000" />
            <SubHandlingData>
                <Item type="CCarHandlingData">
                    <fBackEndPopUpCarImpulseMult value="0.075000" />
                    <fBackEndPopUpBuildingImpulseMult value="0.030000" />
                    <fBackEndPopUpMaxDeltaSpeed value="0.250000" />
                </Item>
                <Item type="NULL" />
                <Item type="NULL" />
            </SubHandlingData>
        </Item>
    </HandlingData>
</<CHandlingDataMgr>
```

If I wanted to reduce the values of all of the "fMass" tags by 25 percent and reduce the values of all "fSteeringlock" values by 50 percent, how would I go about doing this? What tools should I use?

Comment: This question is too broad.  There are many, many ways to do this.  What language(s) do you plan to use/have access to?  What have you attempted?  A solution using just XSLT would look different from a solution in Java or C#, and would be different still if you're going to be using Python or PHP or...

Comment: I've tried nothing because I know nothing. I've only ever edited XML files in Notepad++, manually. I would just like the simplest solution; I don't care what tool or what language. I have moderate experience in coding: batch, VBS, PHP, C clones used in various video games, JavaScript. I'd rather not have to compile anything but if that's the most versatile solution, I'll take it.

Comment: I'd encourage you to do a little research on XSLT processors.  that'd offer you a "no compile" solution. Once you've had a chance to attempt some XSLT, you could come back and update the question if you have something more specific.

Comment: I don't have any need to turn the XML document into some other format. I literally just want to scan the document for specific tags and change the values of every matching tag by a certain percentage; that way the changes are uniformly relative across each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try C# XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication37
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            List<XElement> Items = doc.Descendants("Item").ToList();
            XAttribute value = null;
            foreach (XElement item in Items)
            {
                XElement fMass = item.Element("fMass");
                if (fMass != null)
                {
                    value = item.Element("fMass").Attribute("value");
                    fMass.Value = (0.75 * ((double)value)).ToString();
                }
                XElement fSteeringLock = item.Element("fSteeringLock");
                if (fSteeringLock != null)
                {
                    value = item.Element("fSteeringLock").Attribute("value");
                    fSteeringLock.Value = (0.5 * ((double)value)).ToString();
                }
            }

            doc.Save(FILENAME);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that the lines I posted were the entire contents of the XML file - just an example of the structure. Reproducing the entire file in the code of a program doesn't seem like an optimal solution... I appreciate the response, however.

Comment: I know.  Just used input for testing code.  Will work with your entire file.  Use XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("filename");

Comment: Is there any way to restructure this so it reads from the file externally and then either writes to the same file or creates a copy?

Edit: Just saw your response. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time figuring out how to get it to rewrite the document...

Comment: Add one line : doc.Save(FILENAME);  Update posted coded.  Sorry, I screwed up the code with another posting.  Can you post back my code.

Comment: Found old code and made updates.

Comment: Ah, crap. Then I might have messed it up again. I posted what I have. It works, but only for the first item. I'm currently getting a crash, probably due to other tags in the file. I can post the actual contents and the error.

Comment: I've updated the original post with what more accurately reflects the actual contents of the file I'm editing. The error I'm getting is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This seems to be caused by the nested Item tags.

Comment: There are some Item tags that are missing either fMass or fSteeringLock.  Added tests for null.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I've got it all working now!